# Call a second function in cmd after the previous one finished in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

My python script has two functions. I need to run the first function in order to save pdf files in the second function. And in a cmd I have to run a for loop to extract all the videos in folders. For example,

```
for /R "file path" %G IN (*.mov) Do (py report.py "%G")
```

So, after each .mov file, the code terminates and automatically starts running the second .mov file. However, because I have a second function so instead of running through all the .mov files it calls the second function straight away.
I understand that it's because the program is running in a loop of my python file that's why my second function in my python script gets called straight away after the file was extracted. However, I would like to fix this, please help.

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
def a(): 
     ***some code ***
def b() 
    **some code to save all the csv files, which they all were saved from function a(), 
    in pdfs **  

a() 
b()
```

**OUTPUT SAMPLE**

What I would like to have

```
extracting 1.mov..
extracting 2.mov..
extracting 3.mov..
        .
        .
extracting 10.mov..

(function b() is called)
saved csv to pdf.
```

What I currently have

```
extracting 1.mov..
function b() is called
saved csv to pdf.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Please help me out.

Comment: You need a `for` loop inside function `a` to loop through all the files instead of just one file

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you make the **for loop** to extract all the videos inside the a() function? The problem would be solved!

```
def a(): 
    files = [list of all files to extact]
    for file in files:
       ***some code to extract the file ***

def b() 
    **some code to save all the csv files, which they all were saved from function a(), 
    in pdfs **  

a() 
b()
```

Comment: And you can use the `os` module to choose the files you want.